# PostgreSQL: how to define and use "global" constants

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-types

I am writing a few stored procs that process some batch upload data. Each input line can be flagged for a variety of application errors. I have nearly 100 different types of errors in all, and over a dozen different file load procedures.

In C/C++ the idiom for error codes is a bunch of `#define` or `const` in a project-wide include (class) file and then using the symbolic names in application code. The compilers check for wayward spellings. Java/C# too offer a similar construct. How does one obtain a similar effect in `plpgsql`? I have toyed with setting up these in postgresql.conf but is that a sound approach? It obviously will not work at compile time. And I don't want to grant write privileges to conf files to application developers. Further, it will require a reload of conf for every application change, possibly a system stability issue. I am sure there are many other drawbacks.

In a like vein, I have also a need for plain "user-defined" types wherein I would like to fix the representation of certain application data types, such as "part_number" to be varchar(20), "currency_code" to be char(3) and so on. Again, in C/C++ one would use `typedef` or `struct` as the case might be. So I tried creating a `TYPE` in PostgreSQL for consistent usage across tables, views, function headers. But with the UDTs I ran into a new set of issues: specifying primary keys, and in CSV input specs where the value must now be given in parentheses. Is there a different way of dealing with such objectives in PostgreSQL?

I am new to PostgreSQL. We are using 9.2 on Linux. I am tempted to use a pre-processor but then it will not be compatible with any design tool I have seen.

Comment: _How does one obtain a similar effect in plpgsql ?_ Using an error table?

Comment: what is an "error table"? If this is a postgresql feature could you possibly post a link for it? I started with a table for all error codes but realized it requires a join and, worse, this not a compile-time but a run-time check. I am trying to get out of that. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question you could potentially use an [ENUM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-enum.html) type.

```
CREATE TYPE flag AS ENUM ('ok', 'bad', 'superbad');
```

Which would at least allow for sanity checking of your spellings for each of the flag states.

For your second question *(and please ask multiple questions in the future - since it keeps things on topic)* you might want to look at [DOMAINs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createdomain.html)

Comment: Chris, thanks. I think enum will do until something better came along.